# Ubuntu running slow - java using a huge amount of CPU

Tags: ubuntu, memory, cpu, java, intellij-idea

My work laptop has been completely fine since I first got it four months ago, but all of a sudden in these past few days it is running very sluggish, with seemingly no explanation why. I first noticed this as coding in my IDE was noticeably "laggy" and running unit tests took twice as long.

I am using Ubuntu, and after using the "top" command to monitor memory/CPU usage I noticed whenever I start typing in my IDE, java has extremely high CPU usage and can spike up to >700%.

Here is an example screenshot of my terminal during one of these spikes.
[image]

Does anyone know what might be happening here? I have already tried to uninstall/reinstall both Java and my IDE, but it hasn't made any difference.

Some specs:
Dell XPS 9150
Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz x 8
16GB RAM
Intel HD Graphics 530
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Any linter plugin in your IDE ? (which IDE by the way ?)

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Community edition, but I'm not using any external linting plugins. I have a the same setup as other members of my team and I'm working with the same projects so I know it's not a code or IntelliJ plugin issue.

Comment: please [edit] your question to add informations. you may try `ps auxf | grep 'top usage pid'` to know the effective java program using that much cpu by seing the command line after java. (may worth using `grep -B 5 'pid'` instead of simple grep to see the process tree and what is the caller process also.)

Comment: All that command gives me is: `lewis    11617  0.0  0.0  21300   952 pts/18   S+   14:33   0:00          |       \_ grep --color=auto top usage pid`.

Comment: Read your screenshot, there's a column named PID, this stands for Process IDentifier, it should be a number, not a litteral 'top usage pid'...

Comment: Alright man sorry. Here is what I got now `lewis    14375 79.2  7.6 6445616 1219152 pts/19 Sl+ 14:47  14:21                          \_ java -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Xmx512M -jar /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar
`

Comment: So it sounds like you're IDE is triggering build on save or for other reason as it seems sbt-launch is a builder from scala tooling. (but that's from a google search and out of my knowledge)

Comment: Okay, well, my tests were running when I posted that so I think that wasn't the best example of the slowdown. I just spend a defining some variables in my IDE and did the same thing, and I now get a much more detailed response. It's too long to post here but here is a [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/Bn2dy3cG).

Comment: Again, there's an [edit] button under your question (and I even make it clickable here) to edit your question and add more information to it, comments are awful for formatting and limited in size :)

Comment: I've just added a pastebin link to my previous comment with the new issue, sorry about that. I will edit the main post if I need to post any more bulk text.